# Where down the rabbit hole is the final method that "hands off" the web request to the device driver?

Tags: c#, .net, http, tcp, request

I'm trying to start with `WebClient.DownloadString` (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/webclient.cs,cc8549dcc9a62544) and going down the rabbit hole to find the point a task is made that directly corresponds to the work that the device driver does (if there's one involved? I don't 100% understand networks and so forth).

`DownloadString` -> `DownloadDataInternal` -> `DownloadBits` -> ???

and then I get lost.

In short, what I'm trying to find is the lowest-level C# code that goes into creating the web request and waiting for it to complete.

Comment: There is still a lot of code between the .NET web client and the operating systems network card device driver stack. E.g. Winsock.dll. And even on .NET (C#) layer, it is likely that the web client uses other namespaces (e.g. sockets) for its implementation. Depending on what you are looking for, it might be a better idea to describe the problem you try to solve, which led you to investigating that "rabbit hole".

Comment: Almost certainly it goes into `HttpWebRequest.GetResponse` next. The method is virtual, so just trying to click through the links doesn't get you to the actual implementation. I would think that a Socket is probably at the lowest level in C#.